# AWS DynamoDB Stream python convert native format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I've a Lambda function triggered by a DynamoDB Stream. My problem is the strange format of the event received(with type for each key/value).

Does exists a workaround to convert a whole document in a native python format(without any types). I'm looking for a dynamic solution because in the future I want use this lambda with other DynamoDB table Streams which have different format(multiple dict/list levels)

Example:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventID": "1",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "New item!"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES",
        "SequenceNumber": "111",
        "SizeBytes": 26
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:account-id:table/ExampleTableWithStream/stream/2015-06-27T00:48:05.899",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "2",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "OldImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "New item!"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "222",
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "SizeBytes": 59,
        "NewImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "This item has changed"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "MODIFY",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:account-id:table/ExampleTableWithStream/stream/2015-06-27T00:48:05.899",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "3",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "SizeBytes": 38,
        "SequenceNumber": "333",
        "OldImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "This item has changed"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "REMOVE",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:account-id:table/ExampleTableWithStream/stream/2015-06-27T00:48:05.899",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been using this, it served us well until now:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer

serializer = TypeDeserializer()

def deserialize(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [deserialize(v) for v in data]

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        try:
            return serializer.deserialize(data)
        except TypeError:
            return {k: deserialize(v) for k, v in data.items()}
    else:
        return data
```