# Serialization and Deserialization for DynamoDB stream with Python | TypeDeserializer not helpful

Tags: python-3.x, json-deserialization, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Thank you for all the help and support to me and community.

Trying to go throw SO and few articles over internet, and figure out that to deserializer a dynamoDB **Item**, once can use TypeDeserializer and it works breeze(it handles dataTypes, but not generic k,v pair)

But is there a standard library, using which a ddb stream event can be deserializer? including newImage

```
      {
     "eventID":"1",
     "eventName":"INSERT",
     "eventVersion":"1.0",
     "eventSource":"aws:dynamodb",
     "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
     "dynamodb":{
        "Keys":{
           "Id":{
              "N":"101"
           }
        },
        "NewImage":{
           "Message":{
              "S":"New item!"
           },
           "Id":{
              "N":"101"
           }
        },
        "SequenceNumber":"111",
        "SizeBytes":26,
        "StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
     },
     "eventSourceARN":"stream-ARN"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code snippet which I found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746735/aws-dynamodb-stream-python-convert-native-format). It works well.

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer

serializer = TypeDeserializer()

def deserialize(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [deserialize(v) for v in data]

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        try:
            return serializer.deserialize(data)
        except TypeError:
            return {k: deserialize(v) for k, v in data.items()}
    else:
        return data
```

deserialized your request:

```
{
  "eventID": "1",
  "eventName": "INSERT",
  "eventVersion": "1.0",
  "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
  "dynamodb": {
    "Keys": {
      "Id": "101"
    },
    "NewImage": {
      "Message": "New item!",
      "Id": "101"
    },
    "SequenceNumber": "111",
    "SizeBytes": 26,
    "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
  },
  "eventSourceARN": "stream-ARN"
}
```